# Should teams using GCP services use Application Default Credentials or a repo-wide service account for authentication?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

For local development (including other team members) should we be using application default credentials for our apps, or service accounts when authenticating and using Google Cloud Platform services?

I was thinking that being able to control the individual user permissions instead of a random service account would be better, as it also prevents us from having to revoke the whole service account key if someone leaves the team. Whereas if we used ADC, it would just work as we'd disable their account and remove its permissions. However, the documentation in the Authentication overview contains this note:

> Important: For almost all cases, whether you are developing locally or
>   in a production application, you should use service accounts, rather
>   than user accounts or API keys.

What is the correct authentication method to use for local development?

Answer (score 0):

From the [same page](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/#service_accounts):

> All GCP APIs support service accounts. For most server applications that need to communicate with GCP APIs, we recommend using service accounts, as they are the most widely-supported and flexible way to authenticate.

In this sense, the *randomness* of the service account is determined only on your way of managing it.

For your scenario, *when someone leaves the team*, it would indeed be easier to revoke the user account('s permissions), instead of revoking the key, affecting all using it. In my opinion, both ways are correct and the best way would be the one that best suits your context. The documentation pushes for service accounts as it is *a Google account, as opposed to a specific user, and it can be used for authentication regardless of where your code runs*.